# IBM DB2 v11.5 on RHEL8 - recovering BLOB table

Tags: db2-luw, blob

first of all, thanks to all the gurus..

The problem is:
A table that accepts pdf/jpeg/png file upload from frontend. The table with BLOB defined as below:

```
   "IMAGEDATA" BLOB(3048576) LOGGED NOT COMPACT )
```

The table got too large and we perform the following steps to recover spaces by archiving old data.

rename table A1
create new table A2
export old data based on inserttimestamp to a1.ixf
export latest data to A2.ixf
import into table A2 from A2.ixf
Now we are unable to retrieve the pdf file from table A2. Can I know how to recover the archived data in A1.ixf back to the DB?

Can I copy and replace the backed up the LB data files to the tablespace directory?

65G Jul 3 11:00 SQL00453.LB
65M Jul 3 11:00 SQL00453.LBA

Although the A2 table is with a different tableid. Can we update syscat.tables back to 453 tableid?

Our application actually deconstruct the pdf back to frontend but somehow all pdf seems corrupted. We do have the backup restored in a temporary database with the LB & LBA files intact. But the original database has already been updated with newer transactions data.

Thank you and appreciate the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be familiar with rules of exporting LOB data described in the [LOB export considerations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-lob-export-considerations) topic.

> When exporting tables with large object (LOB) columns, the default
> action is to export a maximum of 32 KB per LOB value and to place it
> in the same file as the rest of the column data. **If you are exporting
> LOB values that exceed 32 KB, you should have the LOB data written to
> a separate file to avoid truncation.**

This means, that if you didn't use the corresponding db2 `export` utility modifier like `modified by lobsinfile` or `LOBS TO` or `LOBFILE` clauses, your LOB values larger than 32 KB were truncated, and you can't recover your data with the truncated copy in the `ixf` file.

Comment: thanks for the pointer..
i'll explore on the modifier options.. since i have the backup dump restored, I can export with the modifier and import it back to the original table, right?

Comment: ok... tested the export command in the temp db and able to recover 1 record back to original table and able to display the pdf!
thanks for the help and below is the command used for future reference:

db2 "EXPORT TO PDF_A1.ixf OF IXF LOBS TO /backup/database SELECT * FROM TABLEA1 where RECORD='SAMPLE001'"

db2 "IMPORT FROM PDF_A1.ixf OF IXF LOBS /backup/database INSERT INTO TABLEA1"